# How can I make a batch update with Waterline.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I update multiple rows with with different value at once?

Like I want turn

```
id | order
-----------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

into

```
id | order
------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Model.query or Model.native() depending on your adapter.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html

Comment: Please elaborate. I don't know how to do batch operation with model. query.

Comment: It depends on what databse your using. But those functions allows you to pass in raw Mongo or SQL commands.